# Turning on\/ff bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

Lest imagine that we have several bundles:

```
- Main
- Admin
- Profile
- Post
- View
- Edit
```

and I want create functional that will turn on\off some of them (except one, MainBubndle, where will be all logic of it). But i don't know how to do it. I even not know where to search\read about it.

Base thing that I want something like this... In admin panel there will be something like 'bundles' and list of them with checkboxes. Where I can turn on\off them. It's easy to create but where should I create this checker(means code part)? And how will look like 'bundle is turned off' in code (means only by exceptions or I can create class\service that will handle it)? Also interesting can I do some kind of listeners (means EventListeners) that will give simple text-response on call if this bundle is turned off? Simple example I call service\controller of bundle that is off, from MainBundle .

Question i think on architecture side but I really don't know how can I do it using symfony2.

Comment: This ain't an easy task - there are many things you need to consider ... re-compiling the container, clearing the (opcode)-cache, checking bundle-dependencies ...

Comment: Yeah I know that it's not easy to do, but where should I look in first and read about it?  I don't even know how to do it 'easy' (means base) way? For beginning...

Comment: You may be better off manipulating the services at a higher level, as @nifr said, the container would need to be recompiled.  You also have the dependencies to consider, simply turning bundles off at the user's or even your own discretion on production will open a massive can of worms if coded even slightly incorrectly.

Comment: Quick question, are you creating a plug-in architecture?

Comment: I guess that's his aim :) Another consideration - you will have to remove the bundle's configuration directives from config.yml aswell (or only register them using the bundle's extension/a compiler pass) when removing bundles -> otherwise you will run into `There is no extension able to load the configuration for "..."` exceptions.

Comment: A good starting point may be disabling the bootstrap and class-cache files in the kernel as one would normally do for debugging purposes. you can find a description on how to do that in the documentation chapter **[Disabling the Bootstrap File and Class Caching](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/debugging.html#disabling-the-bootstrap-file-and-class-caching)** - this will prevent various caching issues when adding/removing your bundles but it will also slow down your application noticeable.

Comment: You can edit the AppKernel.php file and check from the db if a bundle is enabled